# LINQ expression to find XElement and loop through attributes which can each add to listbox

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Ok, here's my basic XML structure:

```
 <device
    name="abc"
    source1="True"
    source2="True"
    ...
    source19="False"
    source20="False" />
```

I need to search the file for the device matching a specific name, and then loop through all all it's attributes. All of them that are true will have a user friendly string based on the option # added to a list box. I can figure out the first part but not the looping, it doesn't seem to be something commonly done.

Comment: can you change the structure so that source## attributes become inner elements of device tag ? I mean <device name="abc"><source id="1" value="True" /></device>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("your XML");
var device = doc.Descendants("device").Select(item => item).Where(
                        item => item.Attribute("name").Value.ToString().Equals("some name")).FirstOrDefault();

if(null != device)
{
    var items = device.Attributes().Select(item => item).Where(item =>  item.Value == "True");
    if(null != items)
    {
        //you can also customize name according to your needs here
        yourListBox.AddRange(items.Select( item => item.Name.ToString() ).ToList());
    }
}
```